# How to prevent autoscroll to focused contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`input` and `textarea` works like I want, but `contentEditable` works differently: when page scrolled, `contentEditable` in focus and new element adds before `contentEditable` browser move scroll automatically.

**How to prevent it? Why is this happening?**

Example: [image]

```js
setInterval(()=> {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "item";
  document.querySelector('.items').appendChild(div);
}, 1000);

window.scrollTo(0, 10);
document.querySelector('div[contentEditable]').focus();
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 2000px;
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div><div contentEditable="true">Put focus here (ContentEditable)</div></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="Input type text"></div>
  <div><textarea>TextArea</textarea></div>
</div>
```

P.S. macOS Safari works like I want, Chrome/FireFox repeats this case.

Comment: The StackSnippet doesn't reproduce the issue in FF89 ..? That is, that the auto focus takes place on every element on the bottom of the body if you're actually writing something, if the element just has focus, it's scrolled out of the view.

Comment: @Teemu using Chrome on Windows and the MCVE shows the error perfectly.